# How to save an access Token from a http json response in angular 2 app?

Tags: javascript, authentication, typescript, angular, access-token

I have this http response from server for my POST request:

```
{"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":35999,"refresh_token":"PvmIMkmgmawTYKrUWUlqRd9pd6itd5JCeHYqKdgoul","access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6InNpZ25pbmdrZXkiLCJ4NXQiOiJYU09MYWdXd0o5YjlSMjE4LV94Q3BidTdKWnMifQ.eyJzdWIiOiJDb21tYW5kQ2VudHJhbDAxIiwicmVhbG0iOiJtb3Rvcm9sYXNvbHV0aW9ucy5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE0NjU5MzI0NzgsInNjb3BlIjpbIm1zaV91bnNhcGlfZ3JvdXBtZ3QucmVhZCIsIm1zaV91bnNhcGlfZ3JvdXBtZ3Qud3JpdGUiLCJtc2lfdW5zYXBpX3ByZXNlbmNlLndhdGNoIiwibXNpX3Vuc2FwaV9sb2NhdGlvbi53YXRjaCIsIm1zaV91bnNhcGlfbWVzc2FnaW5nIl0sImNsaWVudF9pZCI6IkNvbW1hbmRDZW50cmFsIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9pZG1wc2IuaW13Lm1vdG9yb2xhc29sdXRpb25zLmNvbTo5MDMxIn0.LRS8ifL8VoHNikvbBaqU6rvqAWT_QJh0KUvbUAZNuo77DMr7eredwfdtNNptdYGfbWvpq00g3ydViCT1Xh4IFsY8-8jqvvY3FStlp0eUdzfJ9QnYJFDEBzrh1ccjCX4nxmEeLpaMSwvMbMsi1ByJNcu9OnDvBSJC82c3la9EGInyGOTMI08WncVwq-8zkuTrv9K9n4wRmjvX_FHsY_OUSlpyJk1iiM_MLyCjH8nTgjCkNskGOEgSSDLrEfMHhdewSag4jFY3_O9RIzrkT3lOJ8sm6ykH6IdckqxDlva8_Ej23J7zr5el6uUUxy04iQQjxct6ToFH1u0TVrC4uednTQ"}
```

What would be the best angular 2 typescript way to save this token, in order to use it for the further get requests to the api. Local storage , cookie ? how to do it the best way ? 
So far I have only a console response:

```
this.http.post(url, '')
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log('Completed');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get new token data everytime you open up the page, then I'd just store it in a service during runtime.

Otherwise, yes - localstorage is a good place to store your information. You could even make yourself a helper service for the storage:

```
class StorageService {
    static write(key: string, value: any) {
        if (value) {
            value = JSON.stringify(value);
        }
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    }

    static read<T>(key: string): T {
        let value: string = localStorage.getItem(key);

        if (value && value != "undefined" && value != "null") {
            return <T>JSON.parse(value);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

So you could use it like:

```
interface IToken {
    token_type: string;
    expires_in: number;
    refresh_token: string;
    access_token: string;
}

[...]

class TokenService {
    private _token: IToken = null;
    private _url: string = "http://...";

    constructor(private _storageService: StorageService,
                private _http: Http) { }

    getToken(callback: (token: IToken) => void) {
        if (this._token) {
            callback(this._token);
        }
        else {
            this._token = this._storageService.read<IToken>('token');
            if (this._token) {
                callback(this._token);
            }
            else {
                this.http.post(this._url, '')
                    .map(res => res.json())
                    .subscribe(token: IToken => {
                        this._storageService.write('token', token);
                        this._token = token;
                        callback(this._token);
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In other places where you need the token you can now use it like so:

```
this._tokenService.getToken((token: IToken) => {
    // do something here
});
```